# Convert ascii foreign language letters to their equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, ascii, html-entities, non-ascii-characters

I have a lot of text with ascii codes embedded, representing german, spanish or french letters occurring in English words, such as the danish O with a slash through it etc.

Is there a way to convert these into alphanumeric equivalents in PHP?

The codes in the files aren't numeric, they are for instance ASCII clusters of backwards E's and 1/4 signs etc.

A spanish name Like Elizabeth Pena, with the accent on the N has like three strange ASCII characters in its place.

Comment: [Those are not ASCII.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more to be Unicode and you are trying to show it as ASCII code. I'd suggest to try a run with [htmlentities](http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) or [utf8_decode](http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php)

**EDIT:**

A little trick: Write this statement at the beginning of your website and you're signs should be shown propperly:

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Why not? He's got some signs from all over the world, and this is only shown propperly in unicode, I thought?

Comment: What he has is UTF-8. [UTF-8 is not Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).